# Apache vhosts not working after PHP update

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04

I have updated PHP from 5.5 to 5.6 on a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 14.04) using `ppa:ondrej/php` repository. I also updated mod_php to use 5.6. Ever since then, my vhost stopped working. All I ever get displayed when reaching the server is the "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" - `/var/www/html/index.html`.

This is in `apache2.conf`:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Directory `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  1 08:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Nov  1 08:20 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Nov  1 08:20 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Nov  1 08:31 somesite.com.conf -> ../sites-available/somesite.com.conf
```

And the config file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/somesite.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName somesite.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/somesite/public
    <Directory /var/www/somesite/public/>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I substituted the real sitename with "somesite". This config was working before, and I don't see why it shouldn't now... I have updated PHP on 3 other servers as well and it works everywhere else. I'm afraid I have tried all the extent of my server admin knowledge, don't really know what to try next.

Could you point me on how to debug this sort of problem? Thank you!

**EDIT**

This is output of `apache2ctl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server somesite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost somesite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost somesite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/somesite.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Maybe it's the duplicity in `port 80 namevhost somesite.com` entry that is causing this issue? How do I get rid of the first occurrence pointing to default config, without deleting the default config? I want to keep it for security and fallback.

Some related topics might be these:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723820/sites-showing-it-works-page-not-what-is-specified-in-vhost-configs

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83633/have-disabled-apache-site-config-file-000-default-conf-but-it-still-seems-activ

Answer (score 0):

`apache2ctl -S` is going to be your best bet.  It should tell you the sites actively running on your system.  It seems likely that the server is using different paths than you're expecting.

Comment: Could you also provide the contents of 000-default.conf?